# Search all element having x.key=k in list

Tags: algorithm, list, search

I need to search all elements x where x.key = k in a list. I would create an empty list G where information about indexes would be stored.

```
search(L,G,k)
    x <- L.head
    y <- G.head
    i <- 0
    while (x.next != null)
        x <- x.next
        i <- i+1
        if(x.key = k)
            y.next <- new y
            y <- y.next
            y.key <- i
```

Is it correct? How can I write new y properly? I want that if element from L has key k, new element is connected to G list with key i, where i is index.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make some corrections:

```
 while (x != null)
        if(x.key = k)
            do some stuff with y
        i <- i+1
        x <- x.next
```

Because  (x.next = null) is last element, but valid element with data key.

Where is a place to make increment i <- i+1 - depends on numeration convention - zero-based or 1-based

P.S. Are you using dummy head nodes?